# Relating the mean value theorem to the directional derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am having some trouble understanding the process for proving the following statement:

If $f'(x,v) = 0$ is a closed ball $B(x_0,r)$ for all $x$, show that $f$ is constant.

In the proof, we take two elements $x_1, x_2$ in $B(x_0,r)$, then we define the vector $v$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $v = x_2 - x_1$, so $x_2 = v + x_1$. Finally, we apply the mean value theorem so that:

$f(x_1 +v) -f(x_1) = f'(x_1 + \theta v, v) = 0$

I can not see how the above relates to the mean value theorem. Don't we need to divide by the distance between $x_2$ and $x_1$ on the left hand side? Could someone help me to fill in the missing steps?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You see, the problem here is that it should have been $\frac{f(x_1+v)-f(x_1)}{(x1+v)-x1} = f'(x_1+\theta v,v) = 0$ thus $f(x_1+v) = f(x_1)$ right? However $(x1+v) - x1 = v$ is a vector now and not a real number so you can not divide by it and apply mean value theorem directly

Comment: What you should do in this case is to approach a little bit more carefully with the mean value theorem. For any given point $x_1$ in your ball define a new function: $f(t) = (1-t)\cdot x_0 + t\cdot x_1, t \in [0,1]$ This function parametrises the segmen $[x_0,x_1]$ (the center of your ball and any other point inside of it.

Comment: Now, this function is diffrentiable on $[0,1]$ (can you see why?) Thus one can apply the mean vlaue theorem to this function at the points $0$ and $1$ for example as to get $f(x_1) - f(x_0) = f'(\xi)(1 - 0) = 0$

Comment: I'm sorry in my first comment I mistyped the function it should have been $g(t) = f[(1-t)\cdot x_0 + t\cdot x_1], t \in [0,1]$

Comment: Thanks famesyasd - that is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\boldsymbol {#1}}$ Let $F(t) = f(\bm x_1 + t \bm v)$ where $t\in [0,1]$. Then $F(0)=f(\bm x_1), F(1)= f(\bm x_2)$ and $F$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, since each $f'(\bm y, \bm v)$ exists and equals $0$. Now check the differentiability of $F$: for each $k\in (0,1)$, 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {F(k+h) - F(k)}h = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f((\bm x_1 +k\bm v) + h \bm v)-f(\bm x_1 + k\bm v)}h,
$$
and note that
$$
f'(\bm y, \bm v) := \lim_{t\to 0}\frac {f(\bm y + t\bm v) - f(\bm y)}t
$$
provided that the limit exists, we have 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {F(k+h) - F(k)}h = f'(\bm x + k\bm v, \bm v), 
$$
i.e.
$$
F'(k) = f'(\bm x_1 +k\bm v , \bm v). 
$$
So by Lagrange's MVT, 
$$
F(1) - F(0) = 1 \cdot F'(k), 
$$
which is just 
$$
f(\bm x_2) - f(\bm x_1) = f'(\bm x_1 + k\bm v, \bm v), 
$$
as shown in the OP.

To conclude, that "division by $\bm x_1, \bm x_2$" is included in the expression of the directional derivatives.